# CSS3 adjacent sibling selector (+) not working with SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am in the middle of rewriting my current WordPress CSS files to SASS. I am targeting paragraphs appearing right after iframes ([read about that here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)). In my current CSS-file it is written like this:

```
iframe + p {
background: red;
}
```

However with SASS, this is not outputtet when compiling. I suspect it has something to do with SASSs abilities to do calculations. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Works for me: http://sassmeister.com/gist/anonymous/5380032

Comment: Sure there is no syntax error in the lines preceding this example?

Comment: I get no errors when compiling, I'm using Scout app. But I see that it should work, I'll have to look this. Thanks both.

Answer (score 3):

The example you gave is valid SCSS. Your problem stems from something else.

Comment: Yes, I think it does too. I recieve no errors when compiling though. I'll see if I can find out whats wrong. Thanks.